# AngularJs - change default state of slider directive in this instance?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've found a great AngularJS directive 'angularSlideables' by @jbodily that does slideToggle() without need to include jquery.

http://jsfiddle.net/rh7z7w0a/2/

The directive used like this:

```
<div slider="is_open">Content initially hidden</div>
```

Div is toggled like this:

```
<button ng-click="is_open2 = !is_open2" >toggle content</button>
```

Thing is, the div is closed by default, what is the best way to change its initial state to be open?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Why not flip it?

```
<div slider="!is_closed">Content initially hidden</div>

<button ng-click="is_closed= !is_closed" >toggle content</button>
```

If you want to use `is_open` you'll have to set it to true in your controller first.

Comment: Using ! only reverses the effect of clicking the button. What I asked was how do you reverse the initial state of the slider div. I know I have to set it in my controller, I am asking how to do that. $scope.is_open = false/true; does not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Please see updated fiddle with is_open set to true and the content is still hidden on page load: http://jsfiddle.net/rh7z7w0a/9/

Comment: Why do you have if n != o? The initial value is set so it's not running. You can either make it run the first time or perhaps even remove that line: http://jsfiddle.net/pndLhpk4/

Comment: Thanks, that did it, removing that statement allows the default status to be set to either true or false. Perfect!